# Using Font Awesome but font isn't smooth

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm using Font Awesome on this page.

But the text still doesn't look smooth:

[image]

On this site, it's smooth:
https://www.yang2020.com/events/

What am I missing to get it to be this smooth?
[image]

Both pages have `font-family: 'Awesome Font', sans-serif`

Comment: Consider `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

Comment: still doesn't look as nice for some reason, I don't see any changes on chrome

Comment: You can remove strong tag. Just use the span and make it's `font-weight: 700` instead of `font-weight: bold`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because page you have mentioned(working one) have fonts defined in

> https://www.yang2020.com/wp-content/themes/aspire-pro/AvenirNext/avenir_next.css?ver=1.2

---

You need to define font to use it like following in css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Awesome Font';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Awesome Font Bold'),
       url('/wp-content/themes/aspire-pro/AvenirNext/font-files/AvenirNextLTPro-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Awesome Font';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Awesome Font Bold Italic'),
       url('/wp-content/themes/aspire-pro/AvenirNext/font-files/AvenirNextLTPro-BoldIt.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Awesome Font';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: local('Awesome Font DemiBold'),
       url('/wp-content/themes/aspire-pro/AvenirNext/font-files/AvenirNextLTPro-Demi.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Awesome Font';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: local('Awesome Font DemiBold Italic'),
       url('/wp-content/themes/aspire-pro/AvenirNext/font-files/AvenirNextLTPro-DemiIt.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Awesome Font';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: local('Awesome Font Heavy'),
       url('/wp-content/themes/aspire-pro/AvenirNext/font-files/AvenirNextLTPro-Heavy.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Awesome Font';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: local('Awesome Font Heavy Italic'),
       url('/wp-content/themes/aspire-pro/AvenirNext/font-files/AvenirNextLTPro-HeavyIt.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Awesome Font';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Awesome Font Italic'),
       url('/wp-content/themes/aspire-pro/AvenirNext/font-files/AvenirNextLTPro-It.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Awesome Font';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Awesome Font Light'),
       url('/wp-content/themes/aspire-pro/AvenirNext/font-files/AvenirNextLTPro-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Awesome Font';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Awesome Font Light Italic'),
       url('/wp-content/themes/aspire-pro/AvenirNext/font-files/AvenirNextLTPro-LightIt.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Awesome Font';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Awesome Font Medium'),
       url('/wp-content/themes/aspire-pro/AvenirNext/font-files/AvenirNextLTPro-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Awesome Font';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Awesome Font Medium Italic'),
       url('/wp-content/themes/aspire-pro/AvenirNext/font-files/AvenirNextLTPro-MediumIt.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Awesome Font';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Awesome Font'),
       url('/wp-content/themes/aspire-pro/AvenirNext/font-files/AvenirNextLTPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```